# Can Google Bot index transcript of YouTube hosted video?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, google-index, video

We have a number of videos on YouTube, which we embed on our site via iframe/object stuff. Now we want to gain more SEO value by indexing video transcriptions.

I have checked one of our video on YouTube and it contains transcription, which has been generated by YouTube automatically. Does Google Bot index it?

What is better to use object tag or iframe tag for video embedding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is **NOT** currently indexing YouTube transcripts.

Here is how I tested it:

My company released a [TED video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ksEycoNy0E).  It has an automatically generated transcript available by clicking on the transcript icon. If I search on Google for a phrase from the transcript in quotes, (for example "here with the other three number one"), Google finds no results.   If I search for the comments on the YouTube page in quotes (for example "need to get politics out of the news organizations"), Google finds the YouTube video right away.

Answer (score 2):

It won't index it via a normal `<iframe>` or `<object>` embeds. Via the API you can [access the captions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions) and could take that and render it on your page. You could preserve your design/UX by putting that in a `<div>` with a show/hide on it.

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

Video Snippets and Sitemaps – A Guide to Video SEO :

http://blog.woorank.com/2013/05/video-snippets-and-sitemaps-a-guide-to-video-seo/